# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) swift 3, can't read from textField

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var getUrl: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var getUrlLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func changeBtn(_ sender: Any) { 
    if let value = getUrl.text {
        getUrlLabel.text = value
        print(value)
    }
}
```

And it gives an error : EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTIONS (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: checkout both IBOutlet connection.

Comment: Why would you tag your Swift-specifc question as Objective-C?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your xib/storyboard contains a connection that you edited or removed, go the the view and check connection inspector, if it doesn't have additional unneeded connections